# Deploying relevant magento backend changes

Tags: database, magento, deployment, backend

I'm thinking of a good deployment strategy for magento. I already have managed to deploy code with git from my local installation to my stage server. (The jump to live is not a problem then)

Now I'm thinking about how to deploy backend changes like the following:
I'm adding a new attribute set and I want it to be available on my stage and later the live server. Since these settings are in the database, I could just do a mysqldump and restore this dump on my stage/live systems.

But I can't do this, since the database has more data like orders, articles (with current stock availability) and a lot more stuff which I don't want to deploy from my testing system.

How are others handling this deployment "problem"?

Comment: Either you can create manually that attribute set on stage and production or You should use Magento installer scripts.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, I chose the extension Mageploy, which is nicely to install via modman (I prefer modgit which relies on the same data for installation) and already captures a lot important backend settings.

If you need more, it's possible to extend it to more backend settings by yourself (and then contribute to the git project. Pullrequests are concidered quickly)